# Count where one of two columns has length greater than one in AWK

Tags: awk

I am interested in doing this for columns 4 and 5 in `my_file.txt`

I already have a solution to this:

`awk '{print length($4),length($5)}' my_file.txt | awk '$1 > 1 || $2 > 1' | wc -l`

I am fine with using `wc` but my pipe for using awk twice seems bad. Any way to do that in one awk call?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, please do add samples of input and expected output in your question also to make it more clear(not my downvote btw), cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do all that in one awk call:

```bash
awk 'length($4) > 1 || length($5) > 1 { n++ } END { print n }' my_file.txt
```

Comment: `print n+0` to get numeric output even if no lines match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way

```
awk '{i+=length($4)>1||length($5)>1}END{print i}' file.txt
```

Explanation: in GNU `AWK` condition which does hold gives `1` and which does not hold gives `0`. For each line I do increase `i` either by `0` (when condition does not hold) or `1` (when condition does hold), after all lines are processed I `print` value of `i`.
**Disclaimer:** this solution assumes `file.txt` has no less than 1 lines.

Comment: Use `print i+0` to get numeric output even if the file is empty then you don't need the disclaimer. it's also not obvious if `i+=length($4)>1||length($5)>1` means `(i+=length($4)>1)||length($5)>1` or `i+=(length($4)>1||length($5)>1)` or `(i+=length($4))>1||length($5)>1` or something else - some parens (and white space) to make the intent explicit would help a lot.